# Lithium form : how to display the form info in the same page

Tags: lithium

I have a form with a field.
I would like that after the submit button is clicked, i can get the text typed and display it on the same page, just after the submit button. For the first time, how can i check that the button isn't click ?
Could you help me ?
Thank you in advance.
Tien,

Answer (score 0):

To check whether a page has form data submitted, you can do:

`if ($this->request->data) { ... }` in the controller, or

`if ($this->request()->data) { ... }` in the view.